# Safari fixed position issue with Google Maps info window

Tags: google-maps, safari, position, fixed, infowindow

so I have this Google Map that is being produced through their API. I have made some custom info windows, that are a bit hacky as I couldn't manage to style the actual windows in the way that I wanted.

On chrome & firefox they look like this, as it should:

[image: Chrome working fine]

The window you see is created by using the css:

```
.window{
background-color: #FFF7EF;
position: fixed;
margin-left: -95px;
margin-top: -65px;
width: 201px;
height: 85px;
border-radius: 3px;
color: #736357;
padding: 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Yet on Safari, they dont seem to display in the correct position, they turn out like this:

[image]

But when I try and inspect the window, it appears as though it *should* be in the correct place, the image below is when I am hovering over my window with the information in it:

[image]

Furthermore the offset doesn't seem to be a consistent distance, so I can't do a custom position for Safari only.

Not really sure where to start with this, unsure if its an issue with Safari not displaying fixed elements correctly, or if the problem is more deeply lying within my use of the API.

Comment: Couldn't find a proper solution to this, ended up using some Safari specific scripts to remove the styled div and just use the default infowindow instead.